# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 321-322: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, encoding, python-unicode

I am trying to join column values in xlsx file using pandas. I am using the below code to that.

```
(df.astype(str).groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False)
             .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({v: ','.join(x[v].unique()) for v in x})))
```

But, I am getting error like

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 321-322: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Does the same error occur with just `df.astype(str)`?

Comment: Could you add how you create the DataFrame?

Comment: @Sebastian, yes

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame()
file_name = /home/file_name.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(file_name)

Comment: Do you have specific characters in your excel file? like japanese. Also a good idea would be to break the different part of the line to see where the issue comes from.

Comment: yes, it may have. but this nearly 8 million records, we unable to find that position.

Comment: Well if you only need string for your DataFrame, you can use the option `dtype = str` in your `read_excel` function and remove the `astype(str)`. Does it fix the issue?

Comment: @angelwally. As you said we have used dtype=unicode. it is working. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need string for your DataFrame, you can use the option `dtype = unicode` in your `read_excel` function and remove the `astype(str)`.